# Turning a String into an Int java method

Tags: java, string, int

I am trying to create a program that outputs a number of balloons and color of balloons entered by the user. The current problem i'm having trouble with is, I am trying to turn a string into an int so I can easily output the number of balloons. I tested the program with what seemed to work well but the output to the console was 0 no matter what I entered. what am I doing wrong ?

```
package assignment_5_1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_5_1 {
    public static int colorToNumber;
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter The Number of Balloons You Want to See:");
         int nob= input.nextInt();


         String cob;
         System.out.print("Enter the Color You Want The Balloons to Be:");
         cob = input.next();
         String rr= "red";
         String oo = "orange";
         String yy = "yellow";
         String gg = "green";
         String bb = "blue";

         int result = colorToNumber;
         System.out.println(result);


                                       }
    public static int colorToNumber(int ret, int cob, String rr, String oo, String yy, String gg,       String bb)
            {
         if(rr.equals(cob)){ret = 1;}
         if(oo.equals(cob)){ret = 2;}
         if(yy.equals(cob)){ret = 3;}
         if(gg.equals(cob)){ret = 4;}
         if(bb.equals(cob)){ret = 5;}
            return ret;
            }
}
```

Comment: int i = Integer.parseInt(String str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling your method, just assigning to `result` the value of a static variable (`public static int colorToNumber;`) :

```
int result = colorToNumber;
```

Change it to :

```
int result = colorToNumber(cob, rr, oo, yy, gg, bb);
```

You should also get rid of the `ret` parameter of your method and change `cob` to String :

```
public static int colorToNumber(String cob, String rr, String oo, String yy, String gg, String bb)
{
  int ret = 0;
  if(rr.equals(cob)){ret = 1;}
  if(oo.equals(cob)){ret = 2;}
  if(yy.equals(cob)){ret = 3;}
  if(gg.equals(cob)){ret = 4;}
  if(bb.equals(cob)){ret = 5;}
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: how do i call the method

Comment: and maybe avoid comparing an int to a string?

Comment: @jhamon Yep. That (I assume) is a typo, since the `cob` variable in the main method is a String.

Comment: yeah i realized when i looked at it that i had cob as an int not a string

Comment: @Eran I did what you said, and it works now. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Change `int result = colorToNumber;`

**to**

```
int result = colorToNumber("red");
```

**or to**

```
int result = colorToNumber(rr);
```

I think what you wanted was simply return the index of a color defined by you when you provide the color to the method right?

You just need to do **some minor amendments** in your method as below:

```
public static int colorToNumber(String color) //You only need to receive 1 color
{
         int ret=0;
         if(rr.equals(cob)){ret = 1;}
         if(oo.equals(cob)){ret = 2;}
         if(yy.equals(cob)){ret = 3;}
         if(gg.equals(cob)){ret = 4;}
         if(bb.equals(cob)){ret = 5;}
         return ret;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use switch case statements on the colors (String) if your jdk version is after 1.7.

---

I don't see why you would want to pass in **all** the colors and yet your method only return 1 *single* value.